# re-format code in tinymce when I use this to create template

Tags: javascript, templates, tinymce

I use tinymce to edit template, sometime I put some regular expression inside table tag as below:

```
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
{table_rows}
</table>
```

I want to save this template to use in other page but tinymce will move {table_rows} to outside table tag as:

```
{table_rows}
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
</table>
```

How can I prevent reformat code in tinymce so I can save free HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you have put your `{table_rows}` outside a html tag.
Tinymce wraps such text inside the appropriate html tag.

You should wrap your code snippet inside a valid tag.